Page refreshes after clicking a button that updates the page; test/assertion times out with two headings but not one
https://youtu.be/dpYMGGSmRaw
I created a simple test that clicks a button, which adds two headings to the pages. This works if I check the text with toHaveText(). However, if I check number of children with toHaveCount(), the test times out.
function addHeading() {
   const results = document.querySelector('#results');
   const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
   h1.textContent = 'heading1'
   results.appendChild(h1)
   const h2 = document.createElement('h1')
   h2.textContent = 'heading2'
   results.appendChild(h2)
}

const submitButton = document.querySelector('button')
submitButton.addEventListener('click',addHeading)

test (`empty search returns all results`, async ({page}) => {
   await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' }).click({delay: 70});
   await expect(page.locator('#results')).toHaveText('heading1heading2')
   await expect(page.locator('#results')).toHaveCount(2)
})

For the second expect, the page would refresh and I don't think this should happen. If I add only one heading, both tests would pass but the page still refreshes and the heading disappears.
The closest post I found is this one. It mentions using click({delay: 70}), which I tried and did not make any difference.
Why would toHaveCount() time out with two headings but not one, and why would the page refresh?

Note that your JS only selects "the very first <button> it finds" instead of "the button with name "Submit", so whatever else is wrong, you want to fix that query selector to include the name attribute.

.toHaveCount(2) doesn't count the number of children of a locator; it counts the occurrences of elements matching the locator itself.
I think you want to select the h1 elements inside of the results element:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<button>Submit</button>
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
function addHeading() {
  const results = document.querySelector("#results");
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.textContent = "heading1";
  results.appendChild(h1);
  const h2 = document.createElement("h1");
  h2.textContent = "heading2";
  results.appendChild(h2);
}
const submitButton = document.querySelector("button");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", addHeading);
</script>
</body></html>`;

test("empty search returns all results", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: "Submit"}).click();
  const results = page.locator("#results h1");
  await expect(results).toHaveText(["heading1", "heading2"]);
  await expect(results).toHaveCount(2);
});

That said, .toHaveCount(2) is now redundant because I've used a better version of toHaveText with an array of two elements. Remove the count assertion.
You can also use await expect(page.locator("#results").getByRole("heading")) if you want to adhere a bit closer to Playwright best practices (getByRole is the preferred locator). You can still restrict it to a particular "level" (e.g. h1) if you want.
As for the page refresh, the code you've provided doesn't reproduce this behavior, but often, clicking a Submit button will trigger a page reload if the page's JavaScript doesn't intercept the form submission event and call event.preventDefault() on it. I'd have to see your actual page, or a more complete reproduction of it to make a recommendation.

Thanks! It seems that I got the toHaveCount(2) wrong (still new to Playwright).
I managed to get toContainText() to work, but not toHaveText() with a string array.

Finally the page refreshing may be the result of the 'live preview' VS code extension I am using when developing locally. I put the code on GitHub pages and the refreshing stops.
